# Error when trying to use AttachDSNLessTable function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 using a dsn-less connection. I'm trying to use the `AttachDSNLessTable` routine but have not been able to get it to work. I get the message

> Run-time error '2425' The expression your entered has a function name that microsoft Access can't not find

I have a macro named AutoExec that runs code AttachDSNLessTable().

I wrote In the AutoExec Macro :

```
AttachDSNLessTable ("Land", "dbo.Land", "ABZAL", "Pdata", "sa", "294285")
```

AttachDSNLessTable Code:

Option Compare Database

```
'//Name     :   AttachDSNLessTable
'//Purpose  :   Create a linked table to SQL Server without using a DSN
'//Parameters
'//     stLocalTableName: Name of the table that you are creating in the current database
'//     stRemoteTableName: Name of the table that you are linking to on the SQL Server database
'//     stServer: Name of the SQL Server that you are linking to
'//     stDatabase: Name of the SQL Server database that you are linking to
'//     stUsername: Name of the SQL Server user who can connect to SQL Server, leave blank to use a Trusted Connection
'//     stPassword: SQL Server user password
Function AttachDSNLessTable(stLocalTableName As String, stRemoteTableName As String, stServer As String, stDatabase As String, Optional stUsername As String, Optional stPassword As String)
    On Error GoTo AttachDSNLessTable_Err
    Dim td As TableDef
    Dim stConnect As String

For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If td.Name = stLocalTableName Then
        CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete stLocalTableName
    End If
Next

If Len(stUsername) = 0 Then
    '//Use trusted authentication if stUsername is not supplied.
    stConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & stServer & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes"
Else
    '//WARNING: This will save the username and the password with the linked table information.
    stConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & stServer & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";UID=" & stUsername & ";PWD=" & stPassword
End If
Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stRemoteTableName, stConnect)
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
AttachDSNLessTable = True
Exit Function
```

AttachDSNLessTable_Err:

```
AttachDSNLessTable = False
MsgBox "AttachDSNLessTable encountered an unexpected error: " & Err.Description
```

End Function

Here is the link to the source http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892490 I used method 1.

Please help me.